# Conversion to logical from cell is not possible error

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a function in MATLAB as follows:

```
function varargout = test_M(varargin)

         I = imread('c:\test.bmp');
         imshow(I); (works fine)

         I = imread(varargin);     % Conversion to logical from cell is not possible error
         imshow(I);

         char a;
         a = varargin;

         disp(a);                 % prints 'c:\test.bmp' on command window
         disp(varargin);          % prints 'c:\test.bmp' on command window

         I = imread(a);   % Conversion to logical from cell is not possible error
         imshow(I);
```

I run the file from command window as follows

```
    test_M('c:\test.bmp');
```

and I get errors as in the title:

> Conversion to logical from cell is not possible

Why does `imread('c:\test.bmp')` work but `imread(varargin)` or `imread(a)` don't?

Answer (score 0):

To unwrap varargin and forward it to other functions you do `varargin{:}`,
i.e. `imread(varargin{:})` in your case.